# Multiple pages for posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, taxonomy

maybe this is answered somewhere just i am not able to find it then sorry.

Situation is that I need to have different "page for posts" for hierarchical post types. example:

CTP: office (hierarchical)
Structure looks like this:

1. Foo Office (acts as separate website)
   1.1 News
   1.2 foo page
   1.2 bar page
2. Bar Office (also acts as separate website)
   2.1 News
   2.2 foo page
   2.2 bar page

Both of these offices need to have "page for posts" i have tried several methods, rewriting post url, adding them to categories, connecting posts to office cpt. but these methods have one major problem:

They cannot have url http://example.com/{office-cpt-slug}/news/{category and subcategory if needed}/post-name

The only solution i see is to create endless hierarchy... witch is not acceptable.

For now the best solution i have found is to create hierarchical categories like

1. Foo office -> News -> category XY
2. Bar office -> News -> category XY

There the problem is, that second level "News" cannot have the same category slug. it can be just news news-1 for example.

Also they have the /category/ slug before their name.

In short, I have multiwebsite WP using CPT, that both websites need to have their separated blog/news page, with correct url structure

Thank you

--- EDIT ---

I am simulating 2 wp installations/instances with CPT called "office".
Top level offices (posts in CPT office with parent 0) are offices(they act as one WP installation) and their child posts are pages (news, contact, about us, find us,...) but somehow i need to use the "posts page" feature of wordpress for each office. /foo/news will be posts page for Foo office and /bar/news will be posts page for Bar office. Problem is that wordpress does not offer this feature by default, and i need to help to figure out some way to add this feature or find a workaround witch fill work as expected

-- real world example (with little modification) --

First lets imagine that lenovo.com is using wordpress even if its not true.

And then lets say that they have on two offices

lenovo.com/nyc and lenovo.com/london

their news page and single post page for different offices will look like

lenovo.com/nyc/news/top-news/we-are-moving-to-dublin

lenovo.com/london/news/top-news/nyc-office-is-moving-to-dublin

Some basic pages will look like

lenovo.com/nyc/contact-us

lenovo.com/nyc/some-another-page

"nyc" and "london" are the post type office with parent id 0 and contact-us, some-another-page is child page of "nyc".

They have different contact pages, different news page (posts page) with different content, but its still one wordpress instance, instead of 2 installations.

these simple child pages like nyc/contact london/aboutus  is not problem, works like charm, but when it comes to "posts page" you cannot tell to WP that nyc->news is posts page for NYC, and london->news is posts page for london.

This needs to be solved

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "page for posts", can you explain what the goal is? Sub sites? Site subsections? By CTP do you mean CPT/Custom post types? Or are you referring to something else? It's not clear what your problem/question is

Comment: CTP = custom post type, page for posts is page that is assigned as page for posts/articles in admin and configrable under settings -> reading -> page for posts, wordpress is single website, and in this case you cannot set more than one pages for posts, that is what i need to do, set page for posts for CTP office with ID XY, and set another page for posts for CTP office with ID XYZ. and yes its kind of sub site, 2 websites in one website

Comment: CPT* best to use the correct accronyms or people will think you're referring to a plugin, you're talking about the posts page set under settings, it doesn't make sense to have multiple of those, so it isn't what you're looking for. Instead you want multiple Archives showing content from different offices. Is the Office CPT purely organisational/for the URL? Or does it contain actual content?

Comment: first thankyou for helping. oh sorry, yes CPT.. .com/foo-office(office CPT with parent 0) is homepage .com/foo-office/about-us is child of foo-office. So bar-office/news will act as posts page for bar-office and foo-office/news will act as posts page for foo-office. also note that i need to keep url hierarchy   to be more correct you can imagine situation that .com/foo-office is one wp instance and .com/bar-office is another wordpress. but i need to do this with one instalation/instance